# Proper translation/explanation for business sector, business field

Tags: translation

I am German. I am currently developing a system which acts like a data provider for company infos.

A company needs to be assigned to one or more "business sectors". I currently deal with companies doing the following:

- Repairing vehicles
- Towing services
- Handicraft businesses
- Motor vehicle experts

The above types I called "business sectors".

Below these can be "business fields", like:

Handicraft businesses

- mason
- carpenter, etc

So my question is, how would a native speaker call these two levels? So far I've seen industrial sectors, branches, etc... I am confused ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Business sectors" or "Industrial sectors" is fine for your first level.

To me the examples in your second list are "trades" or "skills".

By the way (not germane to your specific question) "info" is a mass noun in English. "Infos" is not common and might not be understood.